# Functional dependency and weird rigid type variable errors

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to figure out why the return type is not recognized in this code sample, see [runnable code here](https://repl.it/@coodoo1/functional-dependency-error).

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module Test where

import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Except
import Control.Exception
import Data.Typeable
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy

class Foo m where
  type Inner m :: * -> *
  bar :: Int -> m Int

instance (MonadIO w, Show s, Num s) => Foo (StateT s w) where
  bar current = do
    a <- get
    return a -- error
    -- return 24 -- ok

program :: StateT Int IO String
program = do
      r <- bar 42
      liftIO $ putStrLn $ "output= " ++ (show r)
      return $ "ok"

run :: IO ()
run = do
  (a, s) <- runStateT program $ 777
  putStrLn $ (show a) ++ (show s)
```

and the error message was like below, in my case `MonadState s1 (StateT s1 m)` both `s1` should be `Int` hence I'm not sure why it's not allowed.

```
• Couldn't match type ‘s’ with ‘Int’
    arising from a functional dependency between:
      constraint ‘MonadState Int (StateT s w)’
        arising from a use of ‘get’
      instance ‘MonadState s1 (StateT s1 m)’ at <no location info>
  ‘s’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the instance declaration
    at fsm-try-5-3-q.hs:16:10-55
• In a stmt of a 'do' block: a <- get
  In the expression:
    do a <- get
       return a
  In an equation for ‘bar’:
      bar current
        = do a <- get
             return a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're defining the `Foo (StateT s w)` instance, you aren't constraining `s` to be an `Int`, yet you want to return it from `bar`. How you're using the instance later doesn't matter, because the instance has to be valid on its own.

Perhaps you want to define:

```
instance (MonadIO w) => Foo (StateT Int w) where
    type Inner (StateT Int w) = w
    bar current = do
        a <- get
        return a
```

[Here is your REPL with the modified definition](https://repl.it/repls/UnusedExtrasmallDefinitions).

Comment: Thanks @Koterpillar for the quick reply, it worked like charm!